# JavaScript Regex to match contents inside of matched parenthesis that is most outside?

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to implement a conversion a string: `"(foo)"` to an Array:`[foo]` where `foo` is a nested  structure.

For instance, we have a string :
`"( ('hello' ('world')) (bar) )"`, and this is supposed to be converted to

`[['hello', ['world']], [MasterObj['bar']]]`

To get started, let's the problem simplified,

`"( (foo) (bar) )"`   --**f**-->  `["(foo)", "(bar)"]`

If I can obtain a function to make this job done, the nested object can be finished recursively.

With a very primitive regex, I could write:

```
 var src = "( (foo) (bar) );"

 var src1 = src.match(/\(.*\)/g);
```

src1 = ['**(** *(foo) (bar)* **)**']

At least, matched parenthesis detected.

```
 var src = "(foo) (bar)";

 var src1 =src.match(/\(.*\)/g);
```

src1 = ['**(** *foo) (bar* **)**']
parenthesis is unmatched.

So, here's my question:

How would you match contents inside of matched parenthesis that is most outside?

Is there a common pattern or regex?

Thanks for your thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read someone around here wrote `stuck`, I found a very simple way to match bracket things.

Using regex is rather complicated for this solution.

Say we have a complicated nested list

`(a ((b) (c(d)) e))`

We have a cursor on the string, and

- Start from the head - before the first `(` with `count = 0`, then move the cursor to the end.
- Every time the cursor encounter `(`, increment the count.
- Every time the cursor encounter `)`, decrement the count.
- When the `count === 0` that is the matched `)`.

In this sample, during the cursor moving from the head to the end, the count goes ->

**0 1 2 3 2 3 4 3 2 1 0**  < matched!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but I think you are running up against trying to handle nested patterns with regexes.  I that case, you can't do it.  Regexes just aren't the right tool.

- See:  [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)
- Or for a case more specific to your question: [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: Thanks, I've just found an answer by myself. Please refer my Answer here.